# Publisher ID vs. MY_AD_UNIT_ID, AdMob, Android

Tags: android, admob

i am confused.

1. I created my AdMob account, with Publisher Id: pub-2fffdddcccyyyxxx
2. I didn't add my app to AdMob yet, I would only test how it works
3. I have been follow: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?hl=en#android

**I added:**

```
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);  
    adRequest.addTestDevice("F08D35F3334039343254AD3A83ED11B5");  
     adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

1. Now, I really don't know what is MY_AD_UNIT_ID from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?hl=en#android Publisher Id or "market://details?id=com.your.packagename"?
2. I tried two ways: "pub-2fffdddcccyyyxxx" from AdMob and "market://details?id=com.your.packagename"
3. I always get the answer:
   Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?
   D/webviewglue(16784): nativeDestroy view: 0x4d98e8 onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad request.)

What am I doing wrong? Do you have any idea?

Thanks for help!

Comment: you said you didnt create app to admob, you have to create app-site to get the Publisher ID: your looking for that refers to MY_AD_UNIT_ID

Comment: i said: i didnt add my app to admob, but I create admob and i have Publisher Id: pub-andHereLongNumber. Should I add my app to admob, I mean: admob-> Monetize -> Search for your app...? I want only in test check where the banner/s are displayed.

Comment: once you add app-site to the admob console you get the Publisher ID: for that specific app--site, thats the one you use in programming the add in for MY_AD_UNIT_ID

Comment: thanks JRowan! have to generate AD_UNIT_Id for each banner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add an app--site to the admob console, then you will get the specific Publisher ID: for that specific app-site which refers to the MY_AD_UNIT_ID that you use in your actual program

Answer (score 1):

I Solve this problem follow this instructions [link to tutorial](http://www.redrails.com.br/2013/11/14/solving-problem-in-android-admob-onfailedtoreceiveadinvalid-google-ad-request/)