# How to integrate ads to android app in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I am developing an app in CN1. Now I want to integrate ads to my app. Have been following a tutorial. The problem I am having now is how to get my android adID. Please can anyone help me out. How can I get android adID in codename one

Comment: which tutorial have you been following? there are many ads solutions which one are you trying to integrate?

Comment: I am using AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib extension to arrive at this code for

Comment: I am using AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib extension to arrive at this code for full screen ads:                          
    String admobID = "<Your ANDROID adID>";
    
    if(Display.getInstance().getPlatformName().equals("ios")){
    admobID = "<MY iphone ADID>";
    
    }
    admob = new AdMobManager(admobID);
    
        I created an account with adMob which i was able to get Publisher ID and app ID, now am a little bit confuse maybe adID is my app ID generated from adMob website. pls If am wrong give me a full tutorial link about this. thanks

Comment: Check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528998/publisher-id-vs-my-ad-unit-id-admob-android

Comment: Thanks Sadart Abukari. The link can only be helpful for those that are using Android Studio. I am using codename one. Thanks

Comment: Sadart uses Codename One too. The link contains the same details on where the published ID comes from

Comment: Pls go through my post above, I am asking whether adID is the same thing with app ID generated from adMob website the format is :ca-app-pub-2X7884X2639XXXX0~8X0228XXXX. Thanks

Comment: No. I don't want to go against the play store policy. If I use my real ap ID for testing, they may suspend my account. I want to be very sure before trying that

Comment: Pls I need solution to this problem, am still on this issue. Pls help me out. Any tutorial link that will help me will be highly welcome. Thanks

Comment: I followed this link https://github.com/chen-fishbein/admobfullscreen-codenameoneadmobfullscreen-codenameone for my tutorial in order to display ads. In the sample code that says String admobId = "<your android adID>";  pls Chain, Chen, Sadart and others where can I get my android adID. Am very much confuse here. Help me pls